# find a scalar potential function f for F so that f(0,0)=1

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

I need to find a scalar potential function f for F so that f(0,0)=1.
a force field F(x,y) = <-Sinx,-2Cosy>

First prove F is conservative
`Curl[F[x, y], {x, y}]`
`{a,b} = {D[-Sin[x], y], D[-2 Cos[y], x]}`
I believe because CurlF = 0 or because a=b F is conservative.

now because F=gradF
`{M, N} = {-Sin[x], -2 Cos[y]}`
`f = Integrate[M, x] + h[y]`
`h[y] = Integrate[N, y] + C`

and i think that is a potential function of f but im not sure how to
do the f(0,0)=1 in Mathematica specifically.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to use lower-case notation in Mathematica code, since the pre-defined functions all start with upper-case letters.  In particular, `N` is a pre-defined symbol in Mathematica.

```
{m, n} = {-Sin[x], -2 Cos[y]} 
h[y] = Integrate[n, y] + c
f = Integrate[m, x] + h[y]
```

That said:  you're on the right track.  The value of the constant `c` is determined by the requirement that $f(0,0) = 1$, so you can ask Mathematica to solve that equation for you:

```
csolution = First[Solve[(f /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}) == 1, c]]
f /. csolution

(* {c -> 0} *)
(* Cos[x] - 2 Sin[y] *)
```